# Small login form error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make is a small login form. The user has to type in the username and the password and if the username and password matches the username and password in the database, it should proceed to the home page.

What I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $tUsers_Select = "SELECT ID, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ".$username;
    $tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tUsers_Select);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tUsers_Select_Query);

    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    $dbSecurePassword = md5($dbpassword);

    if(isset($username) AND isset($password)) {

        if ($username == $dbusername AND $password == $dbpassword) {
            echo "Username and password match.";
        }   else {
            echo "Username and password do not match.";
        }
    }   else {
        echo "Username and password are not set";
    }


?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br /><br />

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Errors I'm getting:

[image]

If you need any more details, please comment.

Comment: try  to put isset(username) and isset(password)

Comment: edit this "SELECT ID, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ".$username
as 
"SELECT ID, username, password FROM users WHERE username ="'.$username." ' "

Comment: isset() needs a variable inside.

Comment: Your error messages are because on initial page load your `$_POST` values are not set. Wrap you php code in a `if(isset($_POST['submit']){ ...[your php code]... }` or `if(isset($_POST['username']){ ...[your php code]... }`

Comment: the `$dbconnect` is missing. Of course there will be no result.

Comment: and as @Optimmus pointed out, your `username` is a string, so it needs to be quoted - `...WHERE username = '$username'"`

Comment: I am connected to the database. I removed the connection part. @frz3993

Comment: You should sanitize your input. Learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: (Unsalted MD5 passwords are considered rather insecure these days by the way - don't use this approach if you do not want these passwords to be reversible with a rainbow table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username and password aren't set the first time you load the page.

Change the username/password assignment to use this syntax:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;
```

Then:

```
if (!$username or !$password) {
    //don't run the rest of the PHP login code because nothing was provided
}
```